# Laravel post data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, post

I am adding a order on my database with diferent taxes and I was suprise with this function that work prefectly on local envoirement is not working  wen I deploy the website $tva6, $tva10 and $tva20 still 0.

```
    $tva6 = 0;
    $tva10 = 0;
    $tva20 = 0;

    $cart = session('orderList.orderList');
    foreach ($cart as $item){
        if ($item['tva'] === 6){
            $tva6 += ($item['price'] * $item['qty']);
        }
        if ($item['tva'] === 10){
            $tva10 += ($item['price'] * $item['qty']);
        }
        if ($item['tva'] === 20){
            $tva20 += ($item['price'] * $item['qty']);
        }
    }
    $tva6 = $tva6 - ($tva6 / 1.055);
    $tva10 = $tva10 - ($tva10 / 1.1);
    $tva20 = $tva20 - ($tva20 / 1.2);

    $total = session('orderList.deliSup') + session('DBcart.totalPrice');

    $order = Order::create([
        "user_id"=>Auth::id(),
        "orderId"=>session('orderList.orderIdNaga'),
        "orderList"=>session('orderList.orderList'),
        "payMethod"=>session('orderList.payMethod'),
        "utensils"=>session('orderList.utensils'),
        "infoOrder"=>session('orderList.infoOrder'),
        "totalPrice"=>$total,
        "tva6"=>$tva6,
        "tva10"=>$tva10,
        "tva20"=>$tva20,
        "deliSup"=>session('orderList.deliSup'),
        "deliTime"=>session('orderList.deliTime'),
        "deliDate"=>session('orderList.deliDate')
    ]);
```

Any idea ? thx

edit: $cart is a array with product infos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `$item['tva']` is not integer, use intval for example

```php
foreach ($cart as $item) {
    if (intval($item['tva']) === 6) {
        $tva6 += ($item['price'] * $item['qty']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging $cart to see if the session is actually returning the array you expect.
Otherwise, check the script where the session is generated, as the problem may be there.
If I'm right in my thinking above. send us the script where the session is generated.

Comment: Ok I will add that soon. But I don’t understand why is working locally!!!

Comment: The local settings are really for the purpose of rough testing. many errors are allowed.
If you are using xampp, this kind of constant problem will certainly occur. so it’s always a good idea to test in the production environment to make sure everything is really correct.
Several things that I do locally, when putting online should have some adjustments.

Comment: Some practices acceptable in the local environment are no longer acceptable in the production environment.